# выбор статистики из модели django rest framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как грамотно выбрать статистику из таблицы, есть следующие модели:

```
def get_hour_ts():
    return int(time.time()/3600)


class MainObject(models.Model):
    dt_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Stats(models.Model):
    main_obj = models.ForeignKey(MainObject, related_name='statistic', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shows = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    requested = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dt_hour = models.IntegerField(default=get_hour_ts)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.dt_hour)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("main_obj", "dt_hour"),)
```

далее создаю сериализаторы:

```
class StatsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_shows = serializers.IntegerField()
    total_requested = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Stats
        fields = ['total_shows', 'total_requested']


class MainObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    statistic = StatsSerializer()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    dt_created = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MainObject
```

и в итоге хотел грамотно получить данные по аггрегированной статистике, и использовать минимум запросов к бд, т.е. возможно использовать prefetch_related('statistic').
 ну и получать из одной вьюхи сразу  главный объект, вместе с привязанной статистикой.. пока реализовал через сериализатор и метод поля следующим образом:

```
class MainObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_stats(self, obj):
        stats_query = Stats.objects.filter(main_obj=obj.pk).aggregate(total_shows=Sum('shows'),
                total_requested=Sum('requested'))
        data = StatsSerializer(stats_query).data
        return data

    statistic = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_stats')
```

правда такой подход меня не совсем устраивает, т.к. для каждого объекта выполняется запрос на статистику.. подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно сделать.